# Unity adding navmesh agent but why does the navmeshagent area goes on top of the object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I don't know why, but when I tried to give a ship a navmesh agent, when played it suddenly flipped From this [Normal Ship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCY5b.png) To this [Flippedship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uhjz.jpg). And when I check it, it is because the area of the navmesh agent is on top of the ship like this.[NavMeshAgent area for the ship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IquL.png). Is there anyway to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PlayerUnitShipRoot     <----NavMeshAgent
    PlayerUnitShip     <----Mesh Filter & Mesh Renderer
```

1. Create a new GameObject (PlayerUnitShipRoot).
2. Put your orignial model (PlayerUnitShip) under it.
3. Add a NavMeshAgent on PlayerUnitShipRoot.
4. Move and rotate PlayerUnitShip to a proper position.

Comment: Ah got it, let me try it!!